# Can adjective modify the noun apart from it?

Tags: grammar

> “You yourselves are a case study of what he does. At one time you all had your backs turned to God, thinking rebellious thoughts of him, giving him trouble every chance you got. But now, by giving himself completely at the Cross, actually dying for you, Christ brought you over to God’s side and put your lives together, whole and holy in his presence. You don’t walk away from a gift like that! You stay grounded and steady in that bond of trust, constantly tuned in to the Message, careful not to be distracted or diverted. There is no other Message—just this one. Every creature under heaven gets this same Message. I, Paul, am a messenger of this Message.”
> ‭‭Colossians‬ ‭1:21-23‬ ‭MSG‬

Here, “Christ brought you over to God’s side and put your lives together, whole and holy in his presence.”

I don’t get “whole and holy” part.

Does it serve as an adverb? Or does it modify “your lives”?

But how can they modify apart from “your lives”?
Is this usage common and correct?

Answer (score 3):

It modifies *your lives.*  I have checked other translations of Colossians 1:22, and in most of them *holy* modifies *you.* See https://www.biblehub.com/colossians/1-22.htm

There isn't a problem with an adjective being separated by a few other words from the noun which it modifies.

> He came home that evening, tired but happy.

Comment: Thanks. In your example sentence, “tired but happy” is modifying the subject. Is it common that an adjective modifies the object apart from it besides the Bible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that it makes any difference whether the noun is subject or object. _He found  his mother, when he reached home, very relieved to see him._

Comment: Thank you very much!